# Javafx 2 TreeView - hide root item

Tags: java, treeview, hide, javafx-2

I created my own TreeView in JavaFX 2 with this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/tree-view.htm).
However I want to hide my root node.

How it looks like right now:

- Root element

  - Parent 1

    - Child 1
    - Child 2
  - Parent 2

    - Child 1

How it should look:

- Parent 1

  - Child 1
  - Child 2
- Parent 2

  - Child 1

thanks,
Muki

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Hiding the root item can be done by

```
treeView.setShowRoot(false);
```