# Hiding treenodes in p:tree without removing them

Tags: primefaces, treeview

I have a predefined primefaces tree.

- root

  - sub1

    - sub11
    - sub12
  - sub2

    - sub21

I would like to simply hide the sub1 node with all his children in my webview without removing the Treenodes in my tree.

I thought I could do this by simply provide a boolean to the render property of TreeNode

```
    <p:treeNode rendered=#{!myBean.isSub1()}>
        <h:outputText value="#{node}" render=#{!myBean.isSub1()} />
    </p:treeNode>
```

It doesn't work. Tree is completely shown. But the text for node sub1 is hidden, which prooves, that the value of isSub1() is correct 
and working.

I also tried with stylesheet to hide elements:

```
    <p:treeNode style="visibility:#{(myBean.isSub1())?'visible':'hidden'}>
        <h:outputText value="#{node}" style="visibility:#{(!myBean.isSub1())?'visible':'hidden'} />
    </p:treeNode>
```

doesn't work either. All nodes are visible but Sub1 text is gone.

How can I hide Treenodes ?

Comment: I don't know if it's just a typo here, but the correct name of the attribute is "rendered" not "render"... maybe this already fixes it?

Comment: Thanks for reporting. No that is not the issue. just a quick typo in my question.

Comment: I had the same purpose, but unfortunately PrimeFaces do not offer such a solution as it is possible with [Javafx with TreeView component][1] so the only way at the moment (up to PF v13 inclusive) is to hide the root level with CSS.
[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578992/javafx-2-treeview-hide-root-item?rq=4